# Comma Galore. How do I punctuate “however” in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The importance of this piece, however, is probably better demonstrated in how much it has assisted me to be a photographer.

Maybe it should be like this?

> The importance of this piece, however is probably better demonstrated in how much it has assisted me to be a photographer.

Comment: _Two commas_ ain't commas galore. The first version reads better. And it should be _demonstrated by._

Comment: @user405662 is right on. _However_ in the middle of a clause needs comma intonation (mid-lo-hi-mid) before **and** after. Plus, the complex passive _is demonstrated in_ is limited to objects that are actual nouns like _this picture_, not embedded question complement clauses. If you want to use such a complement, the standard agent phrase preposition for the passive _is demonstrated_ is _by_, not _in_.

Comment: And, by the way, _galore_ is an odd adjective because it must follow the noun it modifies, and also because it must modify a mass noun or a count noun in the plural. Commas are countable, so *_comma galore_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: @John Lawler Sister of the Bond Girl?

Answer (score 3):

When using however in this sense, as a synonym for "though" or "nevertheless," punctuate it as in your first version.

Since surrounding commas are commonly used for this sense of however, leaving one out leads the reader to believe that you are using however as a synonym for "in whatever way," and that makes the whole sentence confusing.